# Create a tree view or heirarchy in lightning component

Tags: lightning

Any idea on how to create or display a tree or hierarchy structure of record in an object. For example

```
> Usa
    > San Antonio
    > San Francisco
    > New York
> Australia
    > Melbourne
```

Once Usa or Australia is click it will collapse or expand the value of the cities on particular country.

Comment: Sure, I've already written an [old-school](https://gist.github.com/brianmfear/32bd056260cf4850ba15bc5641b6c42f) version, you can now use [lightning:tree](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:tree/example) to generate standard-looking trees in your components.

Comment: Hi @david Reed thanks for your comment. I used the lightning tree the problem with that is you can only click the left side icon to collapse and expand. What I want to achieve is to collapse and expand on clicking the text as well.

Comment: The comment you are responding to is from sfdcfox. I edited your question to fix the formatting.

Comment: I mean, if you don't want to borrow sfdcfox's example and iterate it, your next option is to rebuild one yourself using the [SLDS found here](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/trees/).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example for details see [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:tree/example)
Lightning Component

```
        <lightning:tree items="{! v.items }" header="Roles"/>
    </aura:component>
```

Js Controller

```
({
    init: function (cmp) {
        var items = [{
            "label": "Western Sales Director",
            "name": "1",
            "expanded": true,
            "items": [{
                "label": "Western Sales Manager",
                "name": "2",
                "expanded": true,
                "items" :[{
                    "label": "CA Sales Rep",
                    "name": "3",
                    "expanded": true,
                    "items" :[]
                },{
                    "label": "OR Sales Rep",
                    "name": "4",
                    "expanded": true,
                    "items" :[]
                }]
            }]
        }, {
            "label": "Eastern Sales Director",
            "name": "5",
            "expanded": false,
            "items": [{
                "label": "Easter Sales Manager",
                "name": "6",
                "expanded": true,
                "items" :[{
                    "label": "NY Sales Rep",
                    "name": "7",
                    "expanded": true,
                    "items" :[]
                }, {
                    "label": "MA Sales Rep",
                    "name": "8",
                    "expanded": true,
                    "items" :[]
                }]
            }]
        }, {
            "label": "International Sales Director",
            "name": "9",
            "expanded": true,
            "items": [{
                "label": "Asia Sales Manager",
                "name": "10",
                "expanded": true,
                "items" :[{
                    "label": "Sales Rep1",
                    "name": "11",
                    "expanded": true,
                    "items" :[]
                }, {
                    "label": "Sales Rep2",
                    "name": "12",
                    "expanded": true,
                    "items" :[]
                }]
            },{
                "label": "Europe Sales Manager",
                "name": "13",
                "expanded": false,
                "items" :[{
                    "label": "Sales Rep1",
                    "name": "14",
                    "expanded": true,
                    "items" :[]
                }, {
                    "label": "Sales Rep2",
                    "name": "15",
                    "expanded": true,
                    "items" :[]
                }]
            }]
        }];
        cmp.set('v.items', items);
    }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use [`lightning:tree`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:tree/example#lightningComponentDemo:exampleTree) component which is a standard component provided as a part of the Lightning Component Library.

It has multiple variants such as deeply nested components, `onselect` handler for tree nodes when clicked as well the ability to add child nodes dynamically which you could use.

The sample component code below for your case is as below.

**Lightning Component Markup**

```
<aura:component>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />
    <aura:attribute name="items" type="Object" access="PRIVATE"/>

    <lightning:tree items="{! v.items }" header="Countries"/>
</aura:component>
```

**Javascript Controller**

```
({
    init: function (cmp) {
        var items = [{
            "label": "USA",
            "name": "1",
            "expanded": true,
            "items": [{
                "label": "San Antonio",
                "name": "2",
                "expanded": true,
                "items":[]
            },
            {
                "label": "San Francisco",
                "name": "3",
                "expanded": true,
                "items":[]
            },
            {
                "label": "New York",
                "name": "4",
                "expanded": true,
                "items":[]
            }]
        }, 
        {
            "label": "Autralia",
            "name": "5",
            "expanded": false,
            "items": [{
                    "label": "Melbourne",
                    "name": "6",
                    "expanded": true,
                    "items" :[]
                }]
        }];
        cmp.set('v.items', items);
    }
})
```

Comment: I used the lightning tree the problem with that is you can only click the left side icon to collapse and expand. What I want to achieve is to collapse and expand on clicking the text as well